# Why is there no action or errors following users .on click with the target id and text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After running the below code (1), I wanted the code in (2) to add the username to the variable friendName. Currently there are no console errors returned, but nothing happens either when I click the username text on the page.

What have I done wrong?

(2) Should let user click on username and add to variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#username' ).on('click', 'username', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        friendName = $('id').val();
        console.log(friendName);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="username"></div>
```

(1) JS that runs first to create results displayed to user.

```
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
        imageURLs = [];
        Username = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            var object = results[i].get("toUser");
            imageURLs.push(object.get("pic"));
            Username.push(object.get("username"));
        }

        // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
        console.log(imageURLs);
        console.log(Username);
        for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
            $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");  
            $('#username').append(Username[j]); 
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#username' ).on('click', 'username',` makes no sense, unless you have a `<username></username>` element inside of a `id="username"` element. http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.

Change this:

```
friendName = $('id').val();
```

to this:

```
friendName = $(this).text();
```

`$(this)` will get the current clicked element it. and for getting text between the opening and closing tag of div use [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

and also change this:

```
 $('#username' ).on('click', 'username', function (event) {

});
```

to this:

```
 $('#username' ).on('click', function (event) {

});
```

or if html is coming dynamically after DOM load then:

```
$(document).on('click','#username', function (event) {

    });
```

Comment: thanks, this works. The only issue is that all the names are being added to the variable, not just the one name I click on. I presume this is because all data is held within 1 div? How do I stop that from happening? thanks for your prompts too

Comment: the above code gets the text of the div whatever is in it

Comment: here is a suggestion from me that instead of appending in 1 div create a new div for every iteration in loop like mak div with class username and add it in in a container div, then write click event on class selector and get the cicked div text, the way you doing is little complex how you will know in div on which text is clicked, we can only track which div is clicked

Comment: Thks, I'm sorry to ask for further help...but is there anyway you can give me an example of your idea? I'm a little out of my depth at following you. I'm happy to attempt to try myside to.

Comment: make div ``<div id="container"></div>`` and little modification in your for loop ``for(var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
            $('#container').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");  
            $('#container').append("<div class='username'>'"+Username[j]+"'</div>");`` 
        }

Comment: and now instead of click event with ``#username`` use ``.username`` now it will get the text on the one clicked

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$('#username' ).on('click', function (event) { // removed the filter parameter
    event.preventDefault();
    friendName = $(this).text();  // used $(this) to get current clicked element and text to get 
    console.log(friendName);      // the text inside the div
});
```

The second parameter in your case is the filter, and you are specifying a *username* tag, which doesn't exists.

Check the [jQuery.on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Comment: val() will not get div text

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed it!